# bower install with beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, bower, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using beanstalk to deploy on aws ec2.
My project use bower to manage dependency of libraries.
(But my project's main language is python - flask.)

As I know, I can install other packages by .ebextensions config.
I installed redis with it.

```
packages: 
  yum:
    gcc-c++: [] 
    make: []
sources:
  /home/ec2-user: http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-2.8.4.tar.gz
commands:
  redis_build:
    command: make
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/redis-2.8.4
  redis_config_001:
    command: sed -i -e "s/daemonize no/daemonize yes/" redis.conf
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/redis-2.8.4
  redis_config_002:
    command: sed -i -e "s/# maxmemory <bytes>/maxmemory 500MB/" redis.conf
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/redis-2.8.4
  redis_config_003:
    command: sed -i -e "s/# maxmemory-policy volatile-lru/maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru/" redis.conf
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/redis-2.8.4
  redis_server:
    command: src/redis-server redis].conf
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/redis-2.8.4
```

I added npm and bower but it doesn't work.

```
packages: 
  yum:
    gcc-c++: [] 
    make: []
sources:
  /home/ec2-user: http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-2.8.4.tar.gz
commands:
  redis_build:
    command: make
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/redis-2.8.4
  redis_config_001:
    command: sed -i -e "s/daemonize no/daemonize yes/" redis.conf
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/redis-2.8.4
  redis_config_002:
    command: sed -i -e "s/# maxmemory <bytes>/maxmemory 500MB/" redis.conf
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/redis-2.8.4
  redis_config_003:
    command: sed -i -e "s/# maxmemory-policy volatile-lru/maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru/" redis.conf
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/redis-2.8.4
  redis_server:
    command: src/redis-server redis].conf
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/redis-2.8.4
  npm_install:
    command: "yum install -y npm"
  bower_install:
    command: "npm install -g bower"
  bower_install_packages:
    command: bower install
```

I always face error like it.

```
Upload Complete.
INFO: Environment update is starting.                               
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                         
ERROR: [Instance: i-41397fb2 Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild] command failed with error code 1: Error occurred during build: Command bower_install failed.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Looking for Same! Did you find any solution?

Comment: @theChinmay https://gist.github.com/growingdever/8eb2ae8e5793b9c1cd09
try to use this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/growingdever/8eb2ae8e5793b9c1cd09

I solve this problem by above config.
(that config was written by me.)

Comment: Link is offline :-(

Comment: @Patrick try this one. https://gist.github.com/toughrogrammer/8eb2ae8e5793b9c1cd09

Answer (score 1):

I too had this problem and finally AWS support resolved it for me.
The resolution is:

1) Add the following script to .ebestensions:

```
container_commands:
  01_bower_install:
    command: "export PATH=$PATH; $NODE_HOME/bin/node ./node_modules/bowe/bin/bower -V install --allow-root -F > /tmp/01_bower_install.log"
```

2) Add the following line to package.json (in  scripts element)

```
"scripts": {
  "postInstall": "bower install"
},
```

That's all

Comment: But... Why? "That's all" only if you don't mind blindly copy-pasting code.